# Expected weight split in a sum of independent variables

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $x,y \geq 0$ be independent random variables with the property that $E[x] = E[y]$. Can I infer that

$$P(x \geq E[x] \mid x + y \geq E[x+y]) = 1/2~?$$

My heuristic reasoning is that, since $x$ and $y$ have equal expectations, the weight should be split "fairly" between them. But that, of course, falls far short of a solution.

How can I analyze this rigorously?

Comment: Are you sure you want $t$ as a probability? That doesn't seem to make sense. If we rescale $x$, $y$ and $t$ by some factor, everything is invariant and the probability should be the same, but as you've written it, it scales with $t$. It seems that the right-hand side of the equation should be, if anything, $\frac12$?

Comment: @joriki You're right, I made an error. See corrected question.

Comment: @joriki It was still wrong. I just got rid of $t$ altogether; now I have 1/2 like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even simpler example would be to take a deterministic $X$, i.e., take for example $X=c$ (a.s), you could take $c$ any number you want. Then, $\mathbb{E}[X] = c$ and $\mathbb{P}(X \geq \mathbb{E}[X]) = 1$ which implies that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq \mathbb{E}[X] | X+Y \geq \mathbb{E}[X+Y]) =1$ because $X\geq \mathbb{E}[X]$ always holds (in the deterministic case).

Comment: d'oh! thanks. [fill.]

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't infer that. For simplicity, assume $E[x]=E[y]=0$. Then your equation reads

$$
P(x\ge0\mid x+y\ge0)=\frac12\;.
$$

Consider $x=\pm2$ with probability $\frac12$ each, and $y=\pm1$ with probability $\frac12$ each. Then

$$
P(x\ge0\mid x+y\ge0)=1\;.
$$

Comment: Oh, I forgot about cancellation. I'm actually thinking of $x$ and $y$ positive; is there a counterexample satisfying that? I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** Take the case of $X$ being a Bernoulli with parameter $1/3$, and $Y$ being constant equal to $1/3$.

We have $$\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq \mathbb{E}[X] \} = \mathbb{E}[X]= \mathbb{E}[Y] = 1/3\,,$$

but
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq \mathbb{E}[X] \mid X+Y \geq \mathbb{E}[X+Y] \}
= \mathbb{P}\{ X \geq 1/3 \mid X \geq 1/3 \}
=1\,.
$$

Comment: In fact, if $Y$ is constant, then for any random variable $X$ with finite expectation, $$\Pr[X \ge \operatorname{E}[X] \mid X+Y \ge \operatorname{E}[X+Y]] = \Pr[X \ge \operatorname{E}[X] \mid X \ge \operatorname{E}[X]] = 1.$$

Comment: @heropup True. But I believe that a clear down-to-earth counterexample is better, as in more "impactful."